# Rename file based on grand parent and parent directory and sequentially number multiple files

Tags: powershell, copy, rename, sequential-number

I have a files which are stored in the format

```
C:\Users\xx\test powershell script\studyID\number\filenamedfolder\example.jpg
```

The desired output is:

```
studyID_number_1
```

#the final digit should be sequentially numbered for each instance of the jpg in 'filenamedfolder'.

I have used code given in previous answers to find, rename and copy files to the root directory.

I am using Windows 10 and Powershell:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  1478
```

```bsh
Get-childitem "C:\Users\xx\test powershell script\*" -include *.jpg -recurse |% {

$nextName = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Users\xx\test powershell script\*' -ChildPath $_.name

while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
{
   $nextName = Join-Path "C:\Users\xx\test powershell script" ($_.BaseName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)    
   $num+=1   
}

$ParentOjbect =$_.Directory
$Parent =$ParentOjbect.Name
$GrandParent = $ParentOjbect.Parent
$GreatGran = $GrandParent.Parent
$Extension = $_.Extension
$countRef = [ref] 0

Copy-item $_ -Destination (Join-Path "C:\Users\xx\test powershell script" ('{0}_{1}_{2}{3}' -f $GrandParent,$GreatGran,++$countRef.Value,$Extension))
}
```

I have attempted to use code to sequentially name files but my code is not sequentially naming files when more than one jpg exists in the 'filenamedfolder'. Instead only one jpg is copied and renamed into the root folder.

I have never coded in powershell and I am not sure what I have done wrong. I cannot seem to find an existing answer. Could anyone please suggest an adjustment to get this working?

Comment: Code was taken from @Armand G. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to renumber per directory I suggest to:

- first `Set-Location` to the BaseDir
- do a `Get-ChildItem` with multiple wildcards to keep the same subdir depth
- group by `Directory` and only renumber inside this group

This sample tree:

```
> tree /F
├───studyID1
│   ├───number1
│   │   └───filenamedfolder
│   │           example1.jpg
│   │           example2.jpg
│   │
│   └───number2
│       └───filenamedfolder
│               example1.jpg
│               example2.jpg
│
└───studyID2
    ├───number1
    │   └───filenamedfolder
    │           example1.jpg
    │           example2.jpg
    │
    └───number2
        └───filenamedfolder
                example1.jpg
                example2.jpg
                example3.jpg
```

processed by this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\21\SO_56236909.ps1

$BaseDir = Join-Path $ENV:USERPROFILE "test powershell script"
Push-Location $BaseDir

Get-ChildItem -Path *\*\*\* -Filter *.jpg -File |
  Group-Object Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $Cnt=1
    $DirName = $_.Group[0].Directory.Name
    $Number  = $_.Group[0].Directory.Parent.Name
    $StudyID = $_.Group[0].Directory.Parent.Parent.Name
    $_.Group | Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.jpg" -f `
                  $StudyID,$Number,$DirName,$Script:Cnt++ } -WhatIf
  }
Pop-Location
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

yields this resulting tree:

```
> tree /F
├───studyID1
│   ├───number1
│   │   └───filenamedfolder
│   │           studyID1_number1_1.jpg
│   │           studyID1_number1_2.jpg
│   │
│   └───number2
│       └───filenamedfolder
│               studyID1_number2_1.jpg
│               studyID1_number2_2.jpg
│
└───studyID2
    ├───number1
    │   └───filenamedfolder
    │           studyID2_number1_1.jpg
    │           studyID2_number1_2.jpg
    │
    └───number2
        └───filenamedfolder
                studyID2_number2_1.jpg
                studyID2_number2_2.jpg
                studyID2_number2_3.jpg
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite amazing. I must learn some Power shell. Thanks so much for the explanation. I did have to change the code because in the tree my number file came before my studyID file but then it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Ive noticed an issue as (using your resulting tree) some number files have multiple file named folders in them. This results in multiple .jpg with the same file name. Is it possible to alter the code to account for this so that all jpg files have a unique name?

Comment: It was *your* scheme :-), I'll insert an additional `DirName` - Done.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings I appreciate it, that's great.